Loop of charge in a reference frame moving at speed $v$
Image a square loop carrying charge density $\lambda$, and the charges are circulating in the loop at speed $v$ in an inertial reference frame $S$. The sides of the loop are parallel to $x$ and $y$ axes
Now consider an inertial reference frame $\bar{S}$moving at velocity $v$ in $x$-direction relative to $S$. Then in $\bar{S}$, one side of the loop has stationary charges, while the other side has charges moving at $\frac{2v}{1-v^2/c^2}$. Current in the two sides are different. How is this possible? Wouldn't charges get built up somewhere in the loop?

Current is the amount of charge passing through a cross-section of a wire in a unit time interval. For the stationary charges in $\overline{S}$ the wire is moving backwards, so there is still charge passing through cross sections of it.

I don't see why you need to bring special relativity into this. You can make the same thing happen with Galilean relativity. I will replace the Lorentz transform in your question with a Galilean transform to make the math easier for me.
Here's the situation you describe as seen in $S.$ The small red dots represent charges.

Here is the same situation seen from a primed frame $S'$ moving at the right velocity to make the current on the top side of the ring vanish. The current on the opposite side therefore doubles.

You can see there is no charge buildup. I hope you can extend your belief to the slightly more complicated relativistic case.

wait so the charges do not build up even though the current is different in the two segments??? It's a bit counterintuitive to me.

You should include the wire and its motion itself in your mental pictures of the situation, that helps explain why charge is not building up. Of course they would if the wire was still stationary, but that's not the case.

Really nice answer, +1. The animation makes it super clear

Note that at the leading edge of the stationary segment current is coming in and no current leaving. So you do get charge buildup exactly at that leading edge. In the middle of the stationary segment there is no current in or out so there is no buildup. On the trailing edge there is no current in and there is current out so charge is removed. All works as it should
